Empty Form When Initializing from Rest API
I've Defined a 2 pre-rendering processes
1-GEtEmpData : Invoke API (Rest API).
2-Initialize form Employee Home Page.




The Issue is, when the pages open, the Form is Empty and is not initialized.
While I've confirmed from Backend that the API is invoked successfully.
What could be the issue?

Hmmm ... I've seen that you have an Invoke API process as well as a Form Initialization process. Is that intentional? Normally, you'd create your form region with only the Initialization Process ...

Thanks for your reply,
Yes it is intentional, I've followed the same steps applied on YT Video "How to preload an Oracle APEX form with an initial record".
But it is using SQL Data source instead of REST, so i thought it would be same steps.

At the end this is hard to diagnose just based on screen shots - best would be a test case on apex.oracle.com, so that one can review what exactly you have configured ...

Okay, will prepare a test case and share it

@Carsten
I have prepared a sample Workspace (apex.oracle.com) with the same Use Case,
Kindly advise how to share workspace, username, password, privately.

you can send to me by email - carsten{dot}czarskioracle{com}.

Thank you for providing the test case.
In your case, it's the combination of an Invoke API with a Form Initialization process. You can only use one or the other.
The Form Initialization process has special meaning: If the form item, which is marked as Primary Key, has a value, then APEX loads a row from the form source (the REST Data Source) using the value of the primary key. If the primary key is empty, then the form "assumes" a new row, loads nothing and applies Default values to all form items.
An Invoke API process does not look into any form page item and its primary key settings - it simply invokes the API. So in your case, the Invoke API process first loads data from the REST API, then the Form Initialization process (as the primary key items don't have values) clear these out again.
It's perfectly fine to use an Invoke API process to load data into a form - but then make sure not to use the Form Initialization process. Either one, or the other, but not both.

Thanks a lot for your help.
I was able to initialize the form after understanding that i must initialize the PRIMARY KEY with a value before invoking initialize form prcoess.
On my case i was initializing a non-primary key  field.
